# Make a HTTPS request with cert and key create from keytool

Tags: node.js, typescript, https, request, certificate

I had a NodeJS based service, from which I need to consume a HTTPS Service ( A Java service ). So, in order to consume the service I follow the next steps:

- Create a `JKS` format key with the `keytool` cli
- Create a public cert with the `JKS` key
- Pass the public cert to the HTTPS service developer to add the cert to the service
- Import the `JKS` to `PKCS12` format
- Import the `PKCS12` format to `PEM` format key and cert
- Create a `HTTPSAgent` to consume the HTTPS Service and pass the key and cert in `PEM` format

```js
const key = readFileSync('privatekey.pem');
const cert = readFileSync('publickey.pem');
const options: AgentOptions = {
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  passphrase,
  key,
  cert,
};
const httpsAgent = new Agent(options);
```

But when I create the request it throws an error telling me that the server was unable to verify the first certificate.

I'm creating the key and the cert in a bad way or I'm setting wrong the HTTPSAgent?

Comment: are you using express.js ?

Comment: I'm using a server based on express, I can access to the express instance